# ionic icon how to show color

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Icon name: moment.png

This is the icon real color

[image]

But when I input it in my scss file, the color changed to black and white

[image]

This is my **scss file**

```
ion-icon {
    &[class*="minan-"] {
        // Instead of using the font-based icons
        // We're applying SVG masks
        mask-size: contain;
        mask-position: 50% 50%;
        mask-repeat: no-repeat;
        background: currentColor;
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
    }
&[class*="minan-wechatMoment"] {
        mask-image: url(../assets/icon/moment.png);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a coloured png? and use `background-image`

Comment: so change it to 'jpg' can solve this problem? and what you mean background-image?